# Get author login name (or username) from commit

Tags: git, github

It appears I can only get either the author name (John Doe), or the author email (john.doe@acme.org). I can't find a way to get the author login name (johndoe123)

Even the GitHub ["Get a commit" API endpoint](https://docs.github.com/en/rest/reference/git#get-a-commit) won't return the login name.

I need to get the login name to be able to put "@johndoe123" in the changelog of a release so it shows like they do [here](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/releases/tag/v7.2.0-preview.7):

[image]

Any advice?

Comment: A git commit doesn't have a GitHub account, which is presumably what you're looking for. I'd guess you're after https://docs.github.com/en/rest/reference/repos#commits.

Comment: A git commit is linked to an author, and an author is linked to a GitHub user, is it not?

Comment: Not necessarily at all, and certainly not by git - it won't be in the _git_ commit object that endpoint exposes. You want the GH endpoints, not the git ones.

Comment: Yes I understand this is specific to GitHub, it appears some GH API requests returns the login name.

Comment: Yes, but you're looking specifically at the "Git database" section of the API, which won't. Follow the link above to the _GitHub_ commits endpoint. But note that a commit isn't necessarily associated with a GitHub account; I don't know what the API returns in those cases, maybe a `null` author/committer, you'll have to investigate and handle that. You could also look into the [v4 GraphQL API](https://docs.github.com/en/graphql/overview/explorer), which allows you to specify exactly what data you want.

Comment: GitHub uses the email address in order to "link" commits with users.

Comment: @JonathanRioux Not at all. I could define myself as "John Doe <john.doe@localhost>" (in user.name ands user.email in my project) and push into a repo of mine anywhere (using _my_ credentials, which are not linked to a john doe).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

GitHub uses the email address in the commit header to link the commit to a GitHub user.

What does this mean? That the data on the commit doesn't actually have to be equivalent to a GitHub user, since I could have set my commit headers with a different e-mail that the one that I use in GitHub.

On the other hand, if the user who did the commit has a public email address set in GitHub, it's easy to retrieve its user info through the User Search API.

For example, since I have a public email in GitHub if you look for `https://api.github.com/search/users?q=dacamposol@gmail.com` you'll receive the following response:

```
{
  total_count: 1,
  incomplete_results: false,
  items: [
    {
      login: "dacamposol",
      id: 16921751,
      node_id: "MDQ6VXNlcjE2OTIxNzUx",
      avatar_url: "https://avatars.githubusercontent.com/u/16921751?v=4",
      gravatar_id: "",
      url: "https://api.github.com/users/dacamposol",
      html_url: "https://github.com/dacamposol",
      followers_url: "https://api.github.com/users/dacamposol/followers",
      following_url: 
      "https://api.github.com/users/dacamposol/following{/other_user}",
      gists_url: "https://api.github.com/users/dacamposol/gists{/gist_id}",
      starred_url: "https://api.github.com/users/dacamposol/starred{/owner}{/repo}",
      subscriptions_url: "https://api.github.com/users/dacamposol/subscriptions",
      organizations_url: "https://api.github.com/users/dacamposol/orgs",
      repos_url: "https://api.github.com/users/dacamposol/repos",
      events_url: "https://api.github.com/users/dacamposol/events{/privacy}",
      received_events_url: "https://api.github.com/users/dacamposol/received_events",
      type: "User",
      site_admin: false,
      score: 1
    }
  ]
}
```

If the person doesn't have a public email address, maybe you should just refer to the user provided in the `user.name` header in the commit, since maybe that person values its privacy and that's why it didn't set his email as public in GitHub.

Comment: That's exactly what I was looking for! I tried in on GitHub Enterprise, and it returns the 
correct login name linked to the corporate email. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [Get a commit API](https://docs.github.com/en/rest/reference/repos#get-a-commit) to get information about the user who is associated with a commit as the author or committer.  Note that this association is made based on the author and committer email addresses associated with the commit, which suffer from the following limitations:

- The data can generally be forged unless the commit is signed and the key is known to GitHub.
- A user may or may not have a GitHub account, or may have removed a previous email address from their GitHub account, so no user information may be provided.

Comment: I started getting cross-eyed looking at the docs, if I sum up correctly : the doc for the `{repo api url}/git/commits/COMMIT_SHA` endpoint, linked by the OP, the `"author"` and `"committer"` sections *don't* contain a `"login"` field, while the doc for the `{repo api url}/commits/REF` the `"author"` and `"committer"` sections do contain extra details, such as a `"login"` field. I mention this because I couldn't make sense at first of why the OP posted "'Get a commit' won't identify the users", and bk2204 answered "'Get a commit' will identify the user".

Comment: The OP may want to try to target a commit using both endpoints, and confirm wether the endpoints return different informations, or if there is a glitch in the documentation.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [Github GraphQL API](https://docs.github.com/en/graphql) to get the commit and return the `user` object from `author` field:

```graphql
{
  repository(owner: "mui-org", name: "material-ui") {
    object(oid: "97e622215eb8e17dc3597fc35bde9483af37efc3") {
      ... on Commit {
        message
        author {
          name
          email
          user {
            login
            email
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

[Try it in the explorer](https://docs.github.com/en/graphql/overview/explorer)

From [GraphQL doc for the user object](https://docs.github.com/en/graphql/reference/objects#gitactor)

> The GitHub user corresponding to the email field. Null if no such user
> exists.

But as stated in the other answers, there is no guarantee that it will match an existing user, or that the matched user is defacto the commit author. It doesn't mention either what it chooses when there are multiple user matches for this email.

Note that, in the release example you've found, it probably uses some kind of changelog generator (something [like this project](https://github.com/github-changelog-generator/github-changelog-generator)). And what you are looking at are issues/pull requests and not commit. Thus, it extracts the `user` object directly with the pull requests using `GET {owner}/{repo}/pulls` or search API which will return the `user` object:

- pr: https://api.github.com/repos/PowerShell/PowerShell/pulls
- search: https://api.github.com/search/issues?q=type:pr%20repo:PowerShell/PowerShell%20is:merged

For example to reproduce a changelog like [this project](https://github.com/github-changelog-generator/github-changelog-generator), you could [get all the pull requests between the target release and previous release](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48545950/github-api-get-pull-request-for-specific-release-tag) and for each one you will get the `user` object with `login` like [this](https://github.com/github-changelog-generator/github-changelog-generator/blob/e408064ada01edad7bb28de9ef5cbf8ed16d790d/lib/github_changelog_generator/generator/section.rb#L97-L108)

Answer (score 1):

If you are able to use the command line, you can use:

```
git checkout SHA-1
```

to checkout the commit of interest (replacing SHA-1 with the commit number), and

```
git log -n 1 --format="%an"
```

to print the author's name.

Option `-n 1` specifies to output for the top commit only and option --format="%an" specifies to print the author name.

Answer (score 0):

As of the 2022-11-28 API version, this information is available in the [`repos/{owner}/{repo}/commits/{ref}`](https://docs.github.com/en/rest/commits/commits?apiVersion=2022-11-28#get-a-commit) API endpoint.

For [this commit](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/commit/0e106faafe479cdad5df6b95d44159711398c33a), using the [`gh` CLI](https://cli.github.com/) and [`jq`](https://jqlang.github.io/jq/), the `.author.login` key contains the author's GitHub username:

```
$ gh api repos/PowerShell/PowerShell/commits/0e106faafe479cdad5df6b95d44159711398c33a | jq .author
{
  "login": "xtqqczze",
  "id": 45661989,
  "node_id": "MDQ6VXNlcjQ1NjYxOTg5",
  "avatar_url": "https://avatars.githubusercontent.com/u/45661989?v=4",
  "gravatar_id": "",
  "url": "https://api.github.com/users/xtqqczze",
  "html_url": "https://github.com/xtqqczze",
  "followers_url": "https://api.github.com/users/xtqqczze/followers",
  "following_url": "https://api.github.com/users/xtqqczze/following{/other_user}",
  "gists_url": "https://api.github.com/users/xtqqczze/gists{/gist_id}",
  "starred_url": "https://api.github.com/users/xtqqczze/starred{/owner}{/repo}",
  "subscriptions_url": "https://api.github.com/users/xtqqczze/subscriptions",
  "organizations_url": "https://api.github.com/users/xtqqczze/orgs",
  "repos_url": "https://api.github.com/users/xtqqczze/repos",
  "events_url": "https://api.github.com/users/xtqqczze/events{/privacy}",
  "received_events_url": "https://api.github.com/users/xtqqczze/received_events",
  "type": "User",
  "site_admin": false
}
```